# how to connect exist table in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a question: How can I add an table, which already exist in database with EF?

`public DbSet<webpages_Membership> webpages_Memberships { get; set; }`

And model:

```
[Table("webpages_Membership")]
public class webpages_Membership
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
    public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastPasswordFailureDate { get; set; }
    public int PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime PasswordChangeDate { get; set; }
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public string PasswordVerificationToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that - when I try to `update-database`, it create new table `dbo.webpages_Membership` (with prefix dbo), but table witch I want to use is `my_project.webpages_Membership`.

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide schema for table mapping:

```
[Table("webpages_Membership", Schema = "my_project")]
```